# error in building mahout

Tags: maven, mahout

I'm trying to build mahout with this command 
sudo mvn -DskipTests install -e

it build until exmaples but there give me this error!

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (job) @ mahout-examples ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/job.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Mahout Build Tools ................................ SUCCESS [2.496s]
[INFO] Apache Mahout ..................................... SUCCESS [0.663s]
[INFO] Mahout Math ....................................... SUCCESS [20.758s]
[INFO] Mahout Core ....................................... SUCCESS [18.089s]
[INFO] Mahout Integration ................................ SUCCESS [2.467s]
[INFO] Mahout Examples ................................... FAILURE [3.593s]
[INFO] Mahout Release Package ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 48.965s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Sep 01 12:52:34 IRDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 36M/374M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (job) on project mahout-examples: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive job: error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (job) on project mahout-examples: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive job: error in opening zip file
```

how can i fix it!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hexafraction said i have to clear any caches associated with mvn
then i remove ./m2/repository folder in my user. 
because i run command with sudo , then first i use this step:

```
sudo -i    // login as root
cd ./.m2/
rm -r repository/
exit
```

then, try again with  `sudo mvn -DskipTests install -e`

And it works ;)

Answer (score 1):

> error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]

You likely have a corrupt download. Clear any caches associated with `mvn` and try again.

Comment: how can i Clear any caches associated with mvn?